# Avoid Repeating Group by Linq in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, optimization

I need to optimize My Code. I Have Some Repeating Code. But I would like to optimize it. Can any one please help me to optimize My Code. How Can I greate Common Function For this???

```
 foreach (var item in hotellocation.GroupBy(x => x).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count()))
            {
                if (item.Key != "")
                {
                    lstHotelLocation.Add(new HotelLocation()
                        {
                            Name = item.Key,
                            count = item.Value
                        });
                }
            }

            //need to Apply to linq

            foreach (var item in hoteltype.GroupBy(x => x).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count()))
            {               
                if (item.Key != "")
                {
                    lstHotelType.Add(new HotelTypeFilter()
                    {
                        Name = item.Key,
                        count = item.Value
                    });
                }
            }
```

Comment: First thing i'd get rid of is the `ToDictionary` - its pointless as you're never using it as a dictionary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first thing to do is get rid of those `foreach` loops, as they are incongruous with LINQ, and ditch the dictionary, since it's pointless:

```
var lstHotelLocation = hotellocation.GroupBy(x => x)
                                    .Where(g => g.Key != "")
                                    .Select(g => new HotelLocation {
                                        Name = kv.Key,
                                        count = g.Count()
                                    })
                                    .ToList();

 var lstHotelType = hoteltype.GroupBy(x => x)
                             .Where(g => g.Key != "")
                             .Select(g => new HotelTypeFilter {
                                 Name = g.Key,
                                 count = g.Count()
                             })
                             .ToList();
```

If you want to further remove the duplication, you can do this:

```
static List<T> AssembleCounts<T>(IEnumerable<string> values, 
                                 Func<string, int, T> makeObject)
{
    return values.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x))
                 .GroupBy(x => x)
                 .Select(g => makeObject(g.Key, g.Count()))
                 .ToList();
}

var lstHotelLocation = AssembleCounts(hotellocation,
                                      (k, c) => new HotelLocation {
                                          Name = k, count = c
                                      });

var lstHotelType = AssembleCounts(hoteltype,
                                  (k, c) => new HotelTypeFilter {
                                       Name = k, count = c
                                  });
```

Comment: the `count=g.Value` needs to change to `count=g.Count()` (second example only) if you've got rid of the dictionary